# Private gke cluster and external HTTPS loadbalancer health checks failing

Tags: https, google-kubernetes-engine

I have tested a neg deployment in a private and public cluster, however I cannot get the private cluster to work correctly with external loadbalancer, even with suggested fw rules created.

deployment of private cluster fw rules below:

`firewall-rules --allow tcp:30000-32767,tcp:9376 --source-ranges 130.211.0.0/22,209.85.152.0/22,209.85.204.0/22,35.191.0.0/16`

anyone who has done anything similar would be great to have some advice

Comment: Is your exposed neg port 9376/tcp ?, if you are using http/s, then try adding port 80 and / or 443 tcp onto your firewall

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Frank , I was looking in the wrong place, I wasn't aware that the health checks were expecting a 200, the application I had deployed was returning 302 meaning it never thought it was available... so hence failing the health check

Answer (score 0):

When you choose HTTP, HTTPS or HTTP/2 as the protocol for the health check, the probes will require an `HTTP 200 (OK)` response code to be successful and after some retries (also specified in the health check) your backend service will be considered as healthy, each protocol has it own success criteria and need to be taken into consideration for your specific use case:

- [HTTP, HTTPS, HTTP/2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-http)
- [TCP and SSL](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-ssl-tcp)
- [gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-grpc)

For example, if you have a service (not http) running in a specific port, typical use case are databases (mysql, postgree) and you want to ensure that the service is working, you can use a TCP health check, if the handshake is completed, the probe will be successful and request will reach your backends.

Also, you need to configure your firewall rules to allow traffic from the specific ranges, this vary according the LB type (Network Load Balancers require different ranges, this is detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#ip-ranges)), otherwise probes will not be able to reach your backends and will be marked unhealthy.